# Why is the Direction of Particle Vibration Opposite to their Displacement?

Tags: waves, vibrations

[image: I've seen this Transverse Wave diagram in a lot of my books.I dont understand why]

I've seen this Diagram in a lot of my books.I dont understand why the Directions at different nodes are dissimilar (Same for Ant-nodes).What exactly does these vibrating Directions actually mean and Why are they opposite to their actual Displacement?

Comment: Yikes! There is a serious problem with that diagram. The arrows don't all have the same interpretation. Some of them represent velocity and others represent acceleration.

Comment: Really? Well I could'nt find an appropriate diagram at first.But I've made this edit.So can you explain what seems to be my issue of understanding these directions.

Comment: I can't find *any* consistent interpretation of the arrows in the new diagram. It seems like they not be intended to represent velocities, but in that case the scaling is inconsistent. Not to mention the odd choice of where to start the arrows.

Comment: Please state which book(s) this diagram came from including the author.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a wave of the form

$$
u(x, t) = A \cos (kx - \omega t) \tag{1}
$$

In this case the wave propagates towards the "right" (increasing $x$). At any position, the velocity of a point in the medium is calculated with

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = A\omega \sin(kx - \omega t) \tag{2}
$$

This means there's a phase shift of $\pi/2$ between the position and velocity of such point. So for instance, at the left of a maximum in $u$ points are moving down, whereas at the right points are moving up.

The acceleration on the other hand is

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = -A\omega^2 \cos(kx - \omega t) \tag{3}
$$

Now the phase difference is $\pi/2$ with respect to the velocity or, equivalently, $\pi$ with respect to the position. That is, at a maximum in $u$ points are accelerated downwards, and at a minimum, points are accelerated up.

Below there's a sketch. At the top, arrows code the velocity Eq. (2), at the bottom, the acceleration Eq. (3)
[image]

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the wave travelling forward isn't necessarily taking anything with it in the direction of motion.  The "particles" only go up and down, while the wave action itself propagates forward.

Answer (score 0):

First lets make mathematical sense of it.

**Velocity of particle at a point = - (Velocity of wave) x (Slope of wave at that point)**

*This can be derived via  partial differentiation of wave equation (Lets say: y=x(sin(wt-kx))) first w.r.t. time to get particle velocity, then w.r.t. x, to get the slope. They will be related to each other with the coefficient (-w/k) where w is angular frequency. This w/k is also known wave propagation speed or wave velocity. The minus sign is present.*

[image: This implies that whenever slope is negative, velocity of particle will be along positive y axis (minus signs will cancel) . And thats why your diagram looks the way it does.]

Math aside, the best way to 'understand' why this happens is to realize that the wave is constantly moving in the horizontal direction (Transverse wave) and after
some time the blue wave will become the green wave you see. And the arrows precisely show that.

It looks counter-intuitive just because you are incorrectly assuming it is an SHM oscillation which it is not.